# Integrating x^x

Tags: calculus

Couldn't you construct an indefinite integral for x^x by converting it into the following taylor series?
$$x^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }  \frac{(xlnx)^n}{n!}$$ 
$$\int  {x^x}dx=\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }  \frac{(xlnx)^n}{n!}dx$$
and then have an indefinite integral of x^x as an infinite series 
Would this work or is it only a definite integral?

Comment: Yes, you can find the Taylor series of $\int x^x\,dx$ from the Taylor series of $x^x$.  But what you have written is not the Taylor series of $x^x$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang what would be? $$ x^x=e^{xlnx}$$ let $$u=xlnx$$ then wouldn't the taylor series be  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{u^n}{n!}$$